# Block matrix from Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, block-matrices, kronecker-product

I have a vector $\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}_1\\\mathbf{x}_2\end{pmatrix}$ where $\mathbf{x}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mathbf{x}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

**My question is this:** how do I write $\mathbf{x}$ in terms of some linear combination of $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$?

For example, if $n=m$, then one can write $\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \otimes \mathbf{x}_1+
 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \mathbf{x}_2$. This doesn't work when $n \neq m$ because the dimensions of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \otimes \mathbf{x}_1$ and $ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \mathbf{x}_2$ are different.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it might be good to start to design a matrix with a number of rows equal to $nm$, i.e., the dimension you want at the end.

Comment: @VanBaffo number of rows is $n+m$, not $nm$, which gives me doubt that Kronecker product is the right approach

Comment: @VanBaffo but it's still a useful comment

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant $n + m$. I would start by creating a matrix which would lead to your result, and then see if such matrix multiplication might be written in terms of Kronecker products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to manipulate and represent this using linear operators. One way is to zero pad each vector and manipulate the aggregate of the Kronecker product sum using a linear operator. The required sum is represented as:
$$
\mathbf{x} = f\left( \sum_k^N \mathbf{b}_k \otimes \hat{\mathbf{x}}_k\right) = {\mathbf{P}^T\left(\sum_k^N \mathbf{b}_k \otimes \hat{\mathbf{x}}_k\right)} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{x}_k \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\mathbf{b}_k \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ are indicator vectors with an $i$th non-zero scalar $a_k$,  $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_k = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_{k_{m_k \times 1}} \\\mathbf{0}_{(g - m_k) \times 1}\end{bmatrix}$, with $m_k$ as dimension of the $k$th vector, and $g = max(m_1,\ldots,m_k)$. The mapping $f : \mathbb{R}^{(k\times g)} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^h$ can be represented using operator $\mathbf{P}$.

Take an example with three vectors, $k=3$
$$ \mathbf{x}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^l, ~\mathbf{x}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^m,~\mathbf{x}_3 \in \mathbb{R}^n ,\text{with} ~g = max(l,m,n), \text{and} ~h = l+m+n
$$
Let $\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1 \\ \mathbf{x}_2 \\ \mathbf{x}_3 \end{pmatrix}$. Since $l \neq m \neq n$, zero pad each vector,
$$ 
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1 \\ \mathbf{0}_{(g-l) \times 1} \end{bmatrix} \quad \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_2 \\ \mathbf{0}_{(g-m) \times 1} \end{bmatrix} \quad \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3 = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_3 \\ \mathbf{0}_{(g-n) \times 1} \end{bmatrix}
$$
Now perform the Kronecker sum;
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \otimes \hat{\mathbf{x}_1} + 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ a_2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \otimes \hat{\mathbf{x}_2} +
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ a_3\end{pmatrix} \otimes \hat{\mathbf{x}_3} = \begin{pmatrix} a_1\hat{\mathbf{x}_1} \\ a_2\hat{\mathbf{x}_2} \\ a_3\hat{\mathbf{x}_3}\end{pmatrix} = \hat{\mathbf{x}}
$$
If you apply operator $\mathbf{P} = {\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{I}_{l\times l} & \mathbf{0}_{l \times m} & \mathbf{0}_{l \times n} \\
\mathbf{0}_{(g-l)\times l} &\mathbf{0}_{(g-l)\times m} &\mathbf{0}_{(g-l)\times n} \\ 
\mathbf{0}_{m\times l} &\mathbf{I}_{m \times m} &\mathbf{0}_{m\times n}\\
\mathbf{0}_{(g-m)\times l} &\mathbf{0}_{(g-m)\times m} &\mathbf{0}_{(g-m)\times n}\\
\mathbf{0}_{n\times l} &\mathbf{0}_{n\times m} &\mathbf{I}_{n\times n} \\
\mathbf{0}_{(g-n)\times l} &\mathbf{0}_{(g-n)\times m} &\mathbf{0}_{(g-n)\times n}\end{pmatrix}}_{3g \times h}
$, where $\mathbf{I}$ is identity matrix, and $\mathbf{0}$ is zero matrix. Then it can be seen that
$$ 
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{P}^T_{3g \times h} \hat{\mathbf{x}}_{3g \times 1}  = {\begin{pmatrix} a_1\mathbf{x}_1 \\ a_2\mathbf{x}_2 \\ a_3\mathbf{x}_3\end{pmatrix}}_{h \times 1} 
$$
If you plug in $a_k =1$ you get back your unscaled vector.
The biggest effort is probably in constructing the $\mathbf{P}$ matrix, which may not have nice properties.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks for this. The original aim was to differentiate a function of the block vector with respect to each block, but it is no longer necessary, partially because to do so I would need an incredibly complicated matrix like the one described in your question!